# How can I log in my laptop with public key authentication?

Tags: ssh, login

Stemming from my recent aversion to passwords ([this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3887/is-using-a-public-key-for-logging-in-to-ssh-any-better-than-saving-a-password) convinced me), I'm wondering if there's a way to login locally (on my laptop running Crunchbang/Debian) by using public-key encryption.

I figured I could store a private key in a USB stick that I could use to authenticate myself.

I'm both interested in tools, if any, that allow to do this and theory on how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible using PAM.

You might find [PAM_PKA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pampka/) and [PAM-PKCS](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557180) modules useful.